# keep appended relative elements in body

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, append

I'm trying to append divs in random positions with the page's width and height, it works but the divs are placed really far down the page or to the left. I've used screen.width, screen.availWidth and document.body.clientWidth and I can't figure it out. I think its partially because of the div's positioning.

Heres my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var i = 1;
 function createDiv() {
  setTimeout(function() {
   var $newDiv = $('<div></div>').css({
    "position": "relative",
    "width": "100px",
    "height": "100px",
    "background-color": "#ccbfd9",
    "border-radius": "720px"
   });
   $($newDiv).each(function() {
    // document.body.clientHeight
    var leftRandPos = Math.floor((Math.random() *  window.innerWidth));
  var topRandPos = Math.floor((Math.random() *  window.innerHeight));
    $(this).css('left', leftRandPos);
    $(this).css('top', topRandPos);
    $('body').append($newDiv);
   });
   i++;
   if (i < 100) {
    createDiv();
   }
  }, 250);
 }
 createDiv();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: position:absolute should take them where you want.

Comment: thanks it looks really cool now

Answer (score 0):

**Absolute position** is what you are looking for.

```
position: absolute;
top: some px;
left: some px;
```

To get in the center of page (just for fun):

```
 top: 50%;
 left: 50px;
 margin-left: -50px; //half of it's width
 margin-top: -50px; //half of it's height
```

Comment: damn. didn't see the comment. Oh well. at least the question has an answer. :D